# Why berkshelf tries to resolve deleted cookbook?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, berkshelf

I am using berkshelf, chef-solo & vagrant.

I used berks init & berks install to setup one cookbook.

Then i removed this folder, created new cookbook and when i tried to install some libraries, i got following error:

```
Fetching 'deploy_key' from source at ../../../webtest-deploy/cookbooks/deploy_key
The resource at '/Users/true/Sites/webtest-deploy/cookbooks/deploy_key' does not appear to be a valid cookbook. Does it have a metadata.rb?
```

I used `berks shelf uninstall` to uninstall this cookbook, but that did not help. How can i fix that

Comment: have you tried manually removing it from your berkshelf at `~/.berkshelf/cookbooks/<cookbook name>-<version>`?

Comment: Or just purge the entire "~/.berkshelf/cookbooks" directory. It is a cache after all.